# Can't use my local json file text as intiger

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```py
    import multiprocessing
    import urllib.request
    import json
    
    with open("crypto.json") as f:
        data = json.loads(f)
        result = data
    
    print(type(result))
    
    
    resultbtc = int(result['User']['BTC'])
    resultdash = int(result['User']['DASH'])
    resulteth = int(result['User']['ETH'])
    
    url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,DASH,BTC&tsyms=BTC,EUR& api_key=9a96785fb79da776270b5ffc9e989d9092bbe24d23472e107301cec5ff8a82f3"
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = data.read()
    html = html.decode()
    o = json.loads(html)
    btcv = o['BTC']['EUR']
    dashv = o['DASH']['EUR']
    ethv = o['ETH']['EUR']
    fresbtc = btcv * resultbtc['BTC']
    fresdash = dashv * resultdash['DASH']
    freseth = ethv * resulteth['ETH']
    
    
    
    print ("Ο χρήστης",result['Name'],"εχει",fresbtc,"€ σε BITCOIN",freseth,"€ σε ETHEREUM",fresdash,"€ σε DASH")
```

JSON file:

```json
[
 {
    "Name" : "Jonh Smith",
    "BTC" : "23",
    "ETH" : "345",
    "DASH" : "1045"
 }
]
```

I want to extract the values of `BTC`, `ETH` and `DASH` and use them as integers to be able to print their values with real time data but I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\UniPapei\Εισαγωγη στην επιστημη των υπολογιστων\New folder\Εργ 4\bitcoinerg.py", line 20, in 
> data = json.loads(f)
> File "C:\Users\Argyris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 339, in loads
> raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: BTW, as an aside, your JSON values are not JSON numbers, they are JSON strings. Python will deserialize them as `str` objects, not `int` objects. See: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to execute loads on a file handle, not the contents of the file.  Read the file's contents and pass that to json.loads()

```
with open("crypto.json") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    result = data

print(type(result))
```

Comment: why not just use `json.load`?

Answer (score 1):

json.loads() does not accept the file object. Instead use json.load()

```
with open("crypto.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    result = data
```

Comment: why not just use `json.load`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Your suggestion is a much better way to do it, I'll edit the answer.